# Postgresql on external HDD

Tags: postgresql

I had Postgresql installed on a previous MacBook.  However, something happened and now the Macbook won't boot up.  The HDD was okay, so I converted it to an external HDD.

I have another computer with Postgresql installed on it.  However, I need to access the tables from the old HDD, that is an external HDD.

I have found the .conf files and everything like that, and I have attempted to copy and paste, replacing the folders on my new computer with the Postgres folders from the external HDD.

However, this hasn't helped me to call up the old tables.  Can someone help me to either use the GUI Pg3admin tool to call up, or tell me what I need to do in Terminal?

Thank you.

Comment: Also posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/33350571/398670

Comment: @CraigRinger I flagged the other question, it will be either deleted or migrated here. If you plan on answering, please answer this one.